# django UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 87: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use aptana studio 3 for a django project, but got a unicodedecodeerror no matter what i did.

After a lot of unsuccessful google searches, tried a barebones django project. Not a line of code from me, just the start code from aptana.

I expected the usual blank page from django (project working, nothing done yet), but STILL got the encode error. I didn't write a single line of code, so there's no template with latin characters or any other encoding/decoding.

Tried:

Windows->Preferences->General->Workspace->Text file encoding to UTF-8

Right click on project ->Resource->Text file encoding to UTF-8

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- on first line of every file

Nothing Worked.

I'm kind of stuck here. Can anyone help?

Win7 64bit

Error message from console:

```
Validating models...
0 errors found
April 02, 2014 - 17:55:34
Django version 1.6, using settings 'hello.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\bruna\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\hello\src\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
  utility.execute()
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in execute
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
  self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 285, in execute
  output = self.handle(*args, **options)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 76, in handle
  self.run(*args, **options)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 87, in run
  self.inner_run(*args, **options)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 132, in inner_run
  self.stderr.write("Error: %s" % error_text)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 65, in write
  if ending and not msg.endswith(ending):
 File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
  return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 87: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Putting an encoding declaration in your source files has *nothing whatsoever* to do with what happens to data inside that application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the stacktrace (the actual place where you should look for the root cause), there's something about `msg` (most likely, since `ending` is hardly 87 chars long) in `if ending and not msg.endswith(ending):` that isn't valid utf-8. This is probably an encoding issue in a settings file or input parameter.

I suggest to:

- run the whole thing under PDB to see the value of `msg` or add a debug printing of `repr(msg)` before the offending line
- track the origin of the incorrect data. It can very well be a developers' oversight (failure to check input data).

Comment: Debugged the project, and it turns out there's a socket.error: [Errno 10013]. After some more google, changed the server port from 8000 to 8080 and it works!!! Finally!!! It was driving me nuts, but it is finally solved. Thanks Ivan :)

Comment: Could you elaborate on your findings here so it can help further readers? An edit to this answer or a separate answer are probably appropriate ways.

Answer (score 0):

You try:

```
manage.py dbshell
ALTER TABLE database.table MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(255)  CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE
utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;
```

Change database.table and col.
Enjoy !

Comment: it's a blank project, there is no database!

Answer (score 0):

One reason is ,you used sed with grep in the past time like this:

`sed -i "s#views_gaoji#fenye#g"` grep -rl views_gaoji ./`

The above command will modify .pyc file without notification for you.

Then when you start your Django,
Django will start from .pyc,NOT from your engineering file.

Then you will get error without knowing where the error is
OR
you will get error in your `manage.py` file but you never modify it,

**so why did it say,your manage.py has error?**

## ---------------------------------------------------------------------

That's because you *.pyc file are changed by `sed` command

Solution:

`find . -name "*.pyc"  | xargs rm -f`

and then type:

`python manage.py runserver port`